# Problem with domain in vagrant + ansible, trying with example.com and getting example.local instead

Tags: django, nginx, server, ansible, vagrant

i'm having serious problems provisioning and configuring a django web server (with nginx) with vagrant + ansible, everything is ok except one thin, i'm trying to setup a domain 'example.com' to run tests with google oauth but every aproach i do ends up only working in 'example.local', i have no references in all my config files to that .local, is some kind of default or something? what am i missing? im also trying to mount it on a fixed ip with no success.

This is my vagrant setup:

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/bionic64"
  config.ssh.forward_agent = false

  config.vm.define "example.com", primary: true do |app|
    app.vm.hostname = "example.com"
    app.vm.network "private_network", type: "dhcp"
  end

  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--name", "example", "--memory", "1024"]
  end

  config.vm.provision "ansible" do |ansible|
    ansible.playbook = "vagrant.yml"
    ansible.host_key_checking = false
    ansible.verbose = "vv"
  end
end
```

Also i looked up on the guest machien created with vagrant ssh, and looked into nginx sites-enabled and in hte config the setup is correct with example.com domain on it

Part of example nginx config:

```
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name example.com;
    rewrite     ^ https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
}

server {
    listen              443 ssl;
    server_name         example.com;
        ssl_certificate     /etc/ssl/example.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/example.key;
        ssl_protocols       TLSv1.2;
}
```

Comment: How do you associate `example.com` with the ip of the target machine ? Did you add an entry in /etc/hosts ? What is the exact problem you are facing when you connect to that address ? I suggest you have a look at [Vagrant HostManager plugin](https://github.com/devopsgroup-io/vagrant-hostmanager) which can take care of all this for you.

Comment: @Zeitounator in /etc/hosts 127.0.1.1 -> example.com -> example
The problem is when i try to connect example.com is DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN cannot find and the web is working under example.local which does not work with google credentials for google login

I will look that plugin to see if can be useful for me

Comment: Using the plugin i'm getting this error, i don't understand anything, i didn't configured any .local 
==> example.com: [vagrant-hostmanager:guests] Updating hosts file on active guest virtual machines...
The machine with the name 'example.local' was not found configured for
this Vagrant environment.